# Node.js: 404 File not found

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js and trying to deploy my first app on a windows server 2016 using IISNODE with IIS. Everything working perfectly on my localhost, when I moved the site to the server all static files are getting 404 error.

I put the website directly into the wwwroot folder. Please let me know if additional information is needed.

When hoovering my cursor over the 404 file the url "http://mydomain[.]com/star_wars_movie_app/images/star_wars_episode_1_poster.png" which looks correct.

[image]

public folder consist of the following:

- css
- images
- javascript

  ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   var routes = require('./routes');
   var path = require('path');
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

   // Home
   app.get('/star_wars_movie_app', routes.home);

   // movie single
   app.get('/star_wars_movie_app/star_wars_episode/:episode_number?', routes.movie_single);

   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
  ```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a self-hosted server or a server you're renting from someone like Hostgator/Digital Ocean/AWS?

Comment: Yes this is self host on Windows 2016  server.

Comment: for some reason it's looking for the static files in the wwwroot folder and not in the public in in the site folder.